# Java : Convert a awt.Canvas to a container?

Tags: java, canvas, awt

I have a base class `Company_1_Canvas` and another `Company_2_Canvas`.

I would like to put the `Company_2_Canvas` into the `Company_1_Canvas`.

In fact my first canvas should act as a container and not a canvas.

Do you have any idea to do this ?

Remarks : it is a little bit complex to explain why I need this (Design is not wonderfull I know) ! Sorry !

I have try to redefine the 'paint' method of the first canvas, but then the second canvas has NO 'graphics' object because it is not part of the controls hierarchy !

Notice that both canvas have C++ native methods that are playing with the canvas, so I cannot change this !

Comment: Seems to be you're in canvas jail, as Canvas is not a Container and can't contain any other element. Furthermore, I can't imagine how both your component `paint` method will work together.

Comment: java.awt.Panel is what you need... maybe

Answer (score 0):

Optimal solution is to redesign and get away from this mess and `Canvas` completely.

Possible workaround would be to have Canvas1 pass a `Graphics` object to Canvas2 to have it draw on Canvas1.